# php image link in table code

Tags: php, html, image, hyperlink

I have this code in my php dynamic table

```
<?php echo'<a href="http://'.$row_rsInventory['PHOTO'].'"><img src="../images/a-camera-icon.png">'.$row_rsInventory['PHOTO'].'</a>'; ?>
```

When the code runs it displays the link as an image and the text as a hyperlink in the PHOTO field. What do I need to change so that it just shows the link as an image in the PHOTO field. I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Can you explain what you exactly mean by the PHOTO field and what you expect to see there,  the linked image itself or a generic camera icons?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the text you have for anchor `.$row_rsInventory['PHOTO'].`  this way

```
<?php echo'<a href="http://'.$row_rsInventory['PHOTO'].'">
        <img src="../images/a-camera-icon.png">
</a>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the anchor text `.$row_rsInventory['PHOTO']` Use either of the code below

```html
<a href="http://<?php echo $row_rsInventory['PHOTO']; ?>"><img src="../images/a-camera-icon.png"></a>

<?php echo'<a href="http://'.$row_rsInventory['PHOTO'].'"><img src="../images/a-camera-icon.png"></a>'; ?>
```